# How to make objects without renderer selectable with by click in Unity (editor mode)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've created my own sprite renderer using Graphics.DrawMesh() and drawing them in editor mode too. Now i facing a problem: I cannot select sprite with mouse.

So the question is: how can I specify bounds of the object, to let the editor knows the area that can be clicked on to select an object?

Comment: I think you have to maintain separate Gameobject with SpritRender component in scene, then  you could assign your SRender to Gobject like `Gobject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = mySprite;` then you could choose with mouse. take care of Z axis while coding

Comment: I have no unity sprites and SpriteRenderer does not become selectable until any sprite assigned to it.

Comment: You dont need a Sprite. Just set the color of this sprite renderer to be completly transparent. Thanks to this it will be clickable and invisible.

Comment: Well, its sounds like a hack. I'll try to do it this way if there wont be any other good solution.

Comment: Yes, but it is quite common in use, as gives you complete control over what is button and what is not. You can compose the game object as you want. BTW this solution works for sure with `Image` Component, I am not 100% will work with `SpriteRenderer`

Comment: Hi, did you come up with any clean solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: click on the icon above the transform component (left from GameObject name)

[image: imageTage]

Step 2: select one of the colorful oval icons to mark your object. It becomes selectable in scene (editor only)

[image]

Comment: Well, thank for the suggestion, but there will be only tag area clickable. Also, it's too annoying to add this labels to every sprite and scene looks messy.